# How to find a Random Value with negative increments, and positive & negative values in Java?

Tags: java, math, mathematical-optimization

With the data set below, how can I find random numbers between this set, using the math.random function specifically.

-12, -8, -4,  0, 4, 8, 12

```
int secondCase = (int)(Math.random()*7)*(-4)-12;
```

I've been trying the above code along with other things but it does not work for me

Comment: *"it does not work for me"* In what way doesn't it work? What do you get and what did you expect?

Comment: Have you tried using `4` instead of `(-4)`? Alternatively, have you tried using `+12` instead of `-12`?

Comment: One option would be to put the numbers in an array and randomly select an index.  Or `((int)(Math.random() * 7) - 3) * 4` Pick a random num `0 <= r <= 6` Then shift `-3 <= r <= 3` Then multiply by 4.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show an example where random ould work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it with Math.random() because this method returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

Maybe, you can try something like this:

```
    int[] desiredValues  = {-12, -8, -4, 0, 4, 8, 12};

    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int randomIndexBetweenZeroToSix = random.nextInt(7);
        System.out.println("random index: " + randomIndexBetweenZeroToSix);
        System.out.println("desired value: " + desiredValues[randomIndexBetweenZeroToSix]);
    }
```

In this example, I'm just printing the random index of the array and the value of the array based on the random index.

Comment: `randomIndexBetweenOneToSix` Very bad name, since it's ***wrong!***